# 結果発表：9 周年イベント第二弾「Upvote, More!」  ⛄️

Tags: 討議, 投票, キャンペーン

第二弾は、プラス投票イベントです️ ʕ •ᴥ• ʔ ❣️

<sup>*コミュニティでのプラス投票を盛り上げたいと、 @[nekketsuuu](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/users/19110/nekketsuuu) さんが[ご提案](https://nekketsuuu.github.io/assets/slides/2022-12-17-upvote-more.pdf)くださいました。*</sup>

賞品は Stack Overflow オリジナル Koozie（ドリンクホルダー）です。
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

以下、各部門の Winner として上位 2 名、**合計 4 名**にお送りします。

1. 期間中に投稿され、最も高い投票スコアを得た**質問**の投稿者
2. 期間中に投稿され、最も高い投票スコアを得た**回答**の投稿者

**投稿期間：**
2024年1月5日〜1月19日

**投票期間：**
2024年1月5日〜1月28日（1月29日の UTC 0 時以降に順位を調査しますので、その調査時点までに得た投票が有効となります）

**結果発表：**
2024年1月29日

9周年を迎えたこの特別な期間を一緒にお祝いできることを心から嬉しく思います。素晴らしい質問と回答にたくさんのプラス投票を送り、Stack Overflow オリジナル Koozie を手に入れましょう！スタック・オーバーフローユーザのみなさまに、沢山のプラス票と幸せが訪れますように♪

Comment: 受賞者はどのような方法で判定する予定ですか？

Comment: コメントありがとうございます！@mjyさんが以前にチャットでお教えくださった即時性の高い検索インターフェースの[一つ目](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=created%3a2024-1-5..2024-1-19%20is%3aquestion&use=posts&searchOn=3)
と[二つ目](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=created%3a2024-1-5..2024-1-19%20is%3aanswer&use=posts&searchOn=3)
を 1/29 UTC 0時に確認、
再確認用としては @nekketsuuuさんが昔作ってくださったクエリ https://data.stackexchange.com/ja/query/873414
と https://data.stackexchange.com/ja/query/873417
を使う予定でおりましたがいかがでしょうか‍♀️

Comment: 目指す所は明確で、問題なさそうに思います。
冗長かもしれませんが、対象となる投稿が明確になるように少し表現を編集しました。
なお、細かい点に関しては[チャットに投稿](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/64930416#64930416)しました。

Answer (score 4):

**結果発表**：

1. 最も高い投票スコアを得た**質問**の投稿者

**sasaki** さん
[image: sasaki]
[cronファイルに、長いコマンドを複数行にまたがって書きたい。](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/98335/14055)

**小室 敦** さん
[image: 小室-敦]
[pythonからC関数呼び出しの際に構造体アドレス渡しの方法](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/98253/14055)

**たぬきさん** さん
[image: たぬきさん]
[Javascriptをデバッグするときの、Dateの文字列化を変更できるか](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/98354/14055)

2. 最も高い投票スコアを得た**回答**の投稿者

**wtsnjp** さん
[image: wtsnjp]
[cronファイルに、長いコマンドを複数行にまたがって書きたい。](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/a/98342/14055)

**oriri** さん
[image: oriri]
[pythonからC関数呼び出しの際に構造体アドレス渡しの方法](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/a/98258/14055)

**774RR** さん
[image: 774RR]
[golangで標準出力の最後が改行されているかを検出する](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/a/98285/14055)

おめでとうございます！！！Winners のみなさま（同スコアで合計6名）への賞品の発送については、後日メールでご連絡させていただきます。少しだけお待ちくださいませ‍♀️。

たくさんのプラス投票、素晴らしいイベントのご提案、そして細やかなアドバイスを本当にありがとうございました。スタック・オーバーフローのイベントはユーザーのみなさまの個性やアイデアが輝き、楽しい思い出を作れる場でもあります。小さなアクションを大切にしながら、スマートであたたかいコミュニティを築いていけるよう、これからも10周年に向けてどうぞよろしくお願いいたします！